# Mysql timestamp Data truncated for column

Tags: python, mysql, timestamp, truncated

I'm attempting to use python to insert a timestamp into column created_by of a mysql db.

Here is my database table setup..

```
CREATE TABLE temps (
temp1 FLOAT, temp2 FLOAT, created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

temp1 and temp2 and populating correctly but receiving an error for the timestamp

```
 Warning: Data truncated for column 'created_at' at row 1
  cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO temps VALUES (%s,%s,%s)""",(avgtemperatures[0],avgtemperatures[1],st[2]))
((71.7116, 73.2494, None),)
```

Here is the section of python script that inserts information into the db.

```
 #connect to db
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","user","password","temps" )

 #setup cursor
cursor = db.cursor()
ts = time.time()
st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

sql = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temps (
  temp1 FLOAT,  
  temp2 FLOAT,
  created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"""
cursor.execute(sql)


 #insert to table
try:
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO temps VALUES (%s,%s,%s)""",(avgtemperatures[0],avgtemperatures[1],st[2]))
    db.commit()
except:     
    db.rollback()


 #show table
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM temps;""")

print cursor.fetchall()
((188L, 90L),)

db.close()
```

Here is a dump of the db:

```
Dumping data for table temps
temp1   temp2   created_at
71.7116 73.2494 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have to set the datetime. Your created_at column will automatically be updated to the current time stamp at insertion. See documentation at [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

You statement should be

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO temps VALUES (%s,%s,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)""",(avgtemperatures[0],avgtemperatures[1]))
```